# Cannot change memory protection

Tags: linux, ubuntu, memory

I have a tricky problem with memory protection. I am not able to start some programs because of the problems with some libararies. I run into a "cannot change memory" issue.

I mapped the user home to a filepath on a GPFS (5.0.2.3) filesystem. When I map the path via NFS the error didn't occur. ( I was not able to reproduce it). I am at my wit's end. I am note sure if Ubuntu is the one to blame or the mounted gpfs filesystem.

Mainly the error occure when I work with an activated Python environment or working with idl, more specifically,  when I try to load shared libraries (*.so) in the user space

```
user@server:~$ source activate py34
(py34) user@server:~$ python
python: error while loading shared libraries: libpython3.4m.so.1.0: cannot change memory protections

user@server:~/path$ idl
IDL Version 8.5.1 (linux x86_64 m64). (c) 2015, Exelis Visual Information Solutions, Inc., a subsidiary of Harris Corporation.
...
...
% LINKIMAGE: Error loading sharable executable.
             Symbol: sinc_interp, File = /data/home/user/path/bin/sinc_interp.so
             /data/home/user/path/bin/sinc_interp.so: cannot change memory protections
% Execution halted at: $MAIN$
```

### Infos about the Server:

```
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="18.04.2 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"
Kernel=4.15.0-45-generic
```

What can be the reason?

Comment: Solved by reinstalling the whole system...stillt don't know where the error is from and until now didn't occured on the newest installation.